# Nativescript iOS development without a Mac doomed to fail?

Tags: nativescript

I have created some HelloWorld apps on Windows using Nativescript Sidekick and deployed to Iphone. While amazed intriegued that it actually *is* possible to develop on Windows for iOS, it's not very practical without a debugger and/or simulator.  When the HelloWorld crashed on the phone, I have no clue why.

Should I get a Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you need a Windows machine to build apps for Windows Universal, you must need a Mac for iOS.

NativeScript is not the one who makes Mac a must one for iOS development, but hopefully they are planning to come up with something that will enable end to end iOS development on Windows / Linux, it's on their roadmap for 2018.